# How to subset a list in R?

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply, sapply

In the below code, I create a list with the `bootTest()` function, where 5 samples are extracted from the `lung` dataset of the `survival` package. I would like to extract the first iteration in its entirety, as shown in `tmp()` function below. That `tmp()` code is awfully goofy. Is there a clean way to extract, as a dataframe and using the same column headers as the `lung` dataframe, the results of iteration 1 (and 2, then 3, and so on) from `bootTest()`?

Code:

```
library(survival)
data(lung)

bootTest <- sapply(
  1:5,
  function(i) {
    sample_data <- lung[sample(nrow(lung), replace = TRUE), ]
    return(sample_data)
  }
)

tmp <- data.frame(bootTest[1,1],
                  bootTest[2,1],
                  bootTest[3,1],
                  bootTest[4,1],
                  bootTest[5,1],
                  bootTest[6,1],
                  bootTest[7,1],
                  bootTest[8,1],
                  bootTest[9,1],
                  bootTest[10,1]
                  )
```

Comment: `data.frame(bootTest[,1])` should do the trick.

Comment: It would be even easier if you used `lapply()` instead of `sapply()`:  then just `bootTest[[1]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R you can do:

```
data.frame(bootTest[,1])
```

---

```
all.equal(data.frame(bootTest[,1]), tmp)
[1] TRUE
```